# Scheduling phone call with a recruiter

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, human-resources, scheduling

I've been working with a corporate recruiter and have been expecting to hear back about a job offer.  I get an email today saying "let me know a good time to talk".  I replied back and said I was free any time today if she wanted to schedule something, or to feel free to call at any time.

Is this considered ok or is it more appropriate in this situation to suggest a specific time?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this considered ok or is it more appropriate in this situation to suggest a specific time?

I don't see how saying you are available at any time can be unprofessional, so don't worry about that.

It seems you already replied back, so nothing that can be done again this time. However, next time someone asks you for a specific time it will be more efficient if you provided one, instead of giving an open answer like *"any time is fine"*.

This will reduce unnecessary back-and-forth in the communication exchange, and also, as you were given the courtesy to suggest a time, still be polite and professional

Comment: Agreed, definitely better to say "I'm free all day. How does 1pm sound?" It also makes sure you aren't surprised if the recruiter decides to call you when you aren't expecting it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this considered ok or is it more appropriate in this situation to
>   suggest a specific time?

It was okay.

It would have been better if you chose a specific time as you were asked to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're truly free "all day", reply with a specific time and mark that time as "busy" on your calendar. If the recruiter hasn't suggested a specific time, they're likely waiting for you to settle on a time.

Not setting a time yourself can lead to a cycle of "you pick" "no, you pick" and though the indecision, the call never happens.

By suggesting a time, the recruiter can block the time on *his* calendar as well, so that he doesn't land in a situation of getting distracted/too busy during the course of the day and forgetting to call you altogether.

Leaving it open by telling the recruiter "I'm free all day" can cause a conflict with your schedule later in the day because now you have to leave *all day* open to take this call and more or less sit waiting by the phone. No going out shopping, making plans with friends, going to the gym, etc. until you get that phone call finished.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to specify a time that you can have an uninterrupted discussion.

The recruiter is sitting there looking at their calendar wondering when to call you.  They have other scheduled calls to make.

Is "anytime" really good?  What if you're talking with your existing boss when the recruiter calls?  Or if you're just at home, what if they call when you have to leave to pick up your kid from school in 5 minutes?

You set a time and then you ensure you are in a good environment (private, good cell signal, nothing to do in the near future, not where someone's going to come pull you out).

Not setting a time is less convenient for the recruiter and much more likely you make your call with them less professional.

Answer (score 1):

> I replied back and I was free any time today if she wanted to schedule something, or to feel free to call at any time.

I think this is an appropriate response, but it seems like you are only free today to talk. I would suggest you offer options to chat **after today** and if you have **particular time frames you prefer** and what **time zone** you are in. I find that if I don't provide a time frame and time zone, I have recruiters calling me at all hours. For instance, I got a call at 7am PST, which is not good time to call me, but it's good for the recruiter because it's 10am EST for them.